# Magneto Rest API to Update Tracking Number and Carrier Code is not working

Tags: json, magento, magento2, rest

I tried to update the tracking no and carrier code using the following API with the payload.

```
http://example.com/rest/default/V1/shipment/track
```

Payload

```
{
   "entity":{
      "order_id":63,
      "entity_id":26,
      "parent_id":26,
      "weight":2,
      "qty":1,
      "description":"This is testing trackig no",
      "extension_attributes":{
         
      },
      "track_number":"333333",
      "title":"United Parcel Service",
      "carrier_code":"United Parcel Service"
   }
}
```

The above API is found in the documentation link given below.
https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/tag/shipmenttrack

The shipment is done through Magento UI but tracking number and carrier code is not updated.
so I use the Rest API to Update the tracking number and carrier code with the above API.
As per documentation, It has quantity and weight. if I a ship has more than one item, should we give total quantity and weight.

It gives the response with 200 OK but Magento UI is not showing the tracking details.

Is there any restriction to update tracking when order is complete.

It is not working even when the order is "Processing"

Please advise.

Thanks
Rajan

Comment: Maybe a bit late but it's not because response code is 200 that everything goes fine in your request. Try to have a look at `response.text`. For me (another problem) I supposed like you but the `response.text` showed me something like that : `{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"statusHistory"}}` .  A parameter was missing in my payload and despite this, response code was 200

Answer (score 0):

POST URL : `https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/shipment/track`

Please try the following payload,

{
"entity": {
"order_id": 1232,
"parent_id": 1234,
"track_number": "96867546342",
"title": "Delhivery",
"carrier_code": "custom"
}
}

Comment: It would be helpful to mention that you modified the URL. As it is not apparent that it has changed (e.g. the `/default/` part was removed). It would also help if you explained why you think your payload would work. Have you tested it yourself? Also do not forget to use CODE tags for nicer code formatting. Cheers!